# Not permanently saving env

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

Using the commands:

```
RNAVIEW=/Users/Phu/Desktop/Bioinformatics/RNAVIEW; export RNAVIEW

export PATH=/Users/Phu/Desktop/Bioinformatics/RNAVIEW/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Every time I reboot my terminal, I have to keep using these commands if I want to use one of my executable file which is really annoying. Is there a way to keep it stable? My bash_profile below:

[Bash profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49qBI.png)

Whenever I enter these commands, it duplicates the library frameworks. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you make any changes to the bash profile, run the following command to save it permanently in your bash.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```